# Debian package doesn't install items to /usr/src?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm packaging a Debian package which is supposed to simply install some source code in `/usr/src/bcm5974-4.2` and an X configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. It unpacks the configuration file properly, but it doesn't seem to install the `/usr/src/bcm5974-4.2` directory at all.

My project is available [on GitHub here](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19). I'm using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to package it with a pretty simple Makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

PKG_NAME=bcm5974-4.2-dkms
PKG_VERSION=1.0.0
PKG_DESCRIPTION="Backported BCM-5974 module from kernel 4.2 including new MacBook hardware support."

MAINTAINER="NOPE"

all:
    test -d build || mkdir build
    fpm -f -s dir -t deb -n $(PKG_NAME) -v $(PKG_VERSION) -a all -p build/ \
        -d dkms -d build-essential -d linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid \
        -m $(MAINTAINER) --description $(PKG_DESCRIPTION) \
        --post-install scripts/post-install.sh --pre-uninstall scripts/pre-uninstall.sh \
        --post-uninstall scripts/post-uninstall.sh \
        --deb-changelog CHANGELOG \
        --exclude '.git*' usr/
```

This creates a nice little Debian package for me in `build/`:

```
$ dpkg-deb -c build/bcm5974-4.2-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb 
drwx------ 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/X11/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             755 2015-11-04 13:40 ./usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-synaptics-bcm5974.conf
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/doc/bcm5974-4.2-dkms/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             157 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/share/doc/bcm5974-4.2-dkms/changelog.Debian.gz
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/src/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2015-11-04 13:41 ./usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             237 2015-11-03 14:50 ./usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0           32171 2015-11-03 14:50 ./usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/bcm5974.c
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             246 2015-11-03 15:42 ./usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/dkms.conf
```

It seems to have everything I'd want, but it doesn't install the sources to `/usr/src`. How can I get it to install the sources to `/usr/src` properly?

Comment: Using proper Debian packaging is an option. I'm not familiar with fpm. Building packages using `dh` for example, it not terribly hard, and can be quite easy if the package in question has a sane build system and install targets.

Comment: I've debated doing that. I spent a couple hours last night toying with it, but fpm is just so much _easier_. Better: is there a Debian control file which instructs the package where to install things? I find it strange that my conf files are installed but not the DKMS source packages.

Comment: A lot happened in between the makefile and the list of directories.  Usually building APT packages generates tons of log output.  Any clues there?

Comment: It's really weird, I see all of the files in the debian package, and even see their md5 sums, but they're just not installed for some reason.

Comment: The X config file goes to a directory that currently exists, the /usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/ directory won't exist until after this package is installed.  I'd try creating a pre-install script and put `mkdir -p /usr/src/bcm5974-4.2/` and assign the correct permissions with `chmod`.  You could post a link to the `.deb` file.

Comment: Find the deb here: https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19/releases/tag/v1.0.0-ALPHA . I made a pre-install script to create the directory, but it seems like it's never run :-|

Comment: Ah, it's a bug in my scripts, they aren't working like they should.

Comment: `fpm` may not be the best tool for creating your package.  it's hard to take seriously any developer who says "i don't believe in postinst scripts".

Comment: @RobertL, no need to create the directory with mkdir.  dpkg will create dirs as needed on install....remember that at the most basic level it's just a wrapper around `ar` and `tar` - `man 5 deb` for details.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a bug in my pre/post install/uninstall scripts which caused things to be removed at the wrong times.

See, for instance, [this](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19/commit/6a4dd83428421029ce83fb679529b2c07992aca5#diff-b7a499eaeaabb07abcf710375be3fca1R19):

```
rm -fr "/usr/src/$dkms_name-$dkms_version"
```

The Debian prerm hook is called during package updates too, so it seems like this script was removing my source directory during installation.

Comment: Some details would be helpful here.

Comment: Details given above.